# Image not showing in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, database

i am trying get an image from the database to show in the grid. however it seems it is not being shown. may i know the problem to this??

[image]

Here is the code from when i uploaded the image into the database:

```
if (uploadpic.HasFile)
                {
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(uploadpic.FileName);
                    if(ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png")
                    {
                        string query = "Insert into tbl_package(package_name,package_type,package_destination,package_desc,package_price,package_inclusion,package_exclusion,package_picture)" +
                                        "values('" + packnme.Text + "','" + ddlPacktype.Text + "','" + dest.Text + "','" + dscrptn.Text + "','" + packprce.Text + "','" + packinclsn.Text + "','" + packexclsn.Text + "','" + uploadpic.FileName + "')";
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                        {
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                            Response.Redirect("Packages.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ErrorLbl.Text = "Please upload correct file type!";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Side note (but important):That has not been the right way to compose SQL in NET ever.  It is dangerous and prone to many errors. Always use DBParameters.  Pictures are usually stored as blobs and the byte array is passed.  There are many posts here on how to store images.  Nary a week goes by...

Comment: You are storing a file name in the database, not the actual image. What is your html markup? Are you also saving the actual image somewhere?

Comment: <asp:Image ID="Pics" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" 
                                                                        ImageUrl='<%#"data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("package_picture"))%>' />

Comment: You can use the `edit` link to update your question instead of putting updates in comments. The name of the file is not the image data so converting the name of the file to Base64 does not result in an image.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to inspect element(Shortcut Press F12) and select image portion and check which path comes So, You can easily identifying path issue.